# How to convert my site to multi language supported site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multilingual, vs-web-site-project

I developed site using ASP.net & c# it support English language, but now i want to convert my site to 
   Multi language supported site. Any one please explain, how to do it? and what are the problems i face?

Comment: yes, i try this

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: Code only answers do not help answer the question. Please explain your code and how it solves the problem stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**For c# backend:**

- Create a new language project in your solution, give it a name like ProjectName.Language. Add a folder to it called Resources, and in that folder, create Resources files (.resx) for each language you want to support.
- Reference to your project: Right click on `References -> Add Reference -> Prjects\Solutions`.
- Use namespace in a file: `using ProjectName.Language;`
- Use it like: `string someText = Resources.productGeneralErrorMessage`;

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can load the labels and text in your View pages dynamically, with the label data stored in a local database. Depending on the number of expected page request you could use a lite weight database like SQLite.

Place buttons for the user to select a language.

Basic Method:
Install SQLite by NUGET package manager

add a using statement

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
```

Create a database named mydb.db

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("mydb.db");
```

Create a connection method

```
 public const string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\mydb.db;Version=3";
    public static SQLiteConnection ConnectionFactory()
    { return new SQLiteConnection(connectionString); }
```

Create a label Table method:

```
     public void CreateTable()
                {
                              string createTableQuery= 
                                 @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [LabelLanguage] (
                                 [id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                 [labelName] Text NULL,
                                 [englishValue] Text NULL,
                                 [germanValue] Text Null
                                )";

                    using (IDbConnection connection = ConnectionFactory())
                    { connection.Execute(createTableQuery);}

                }
```

Populate database table with info

```
    public void SaveQuery()
```

// a better approach would be to create a list of labels and values the use a for each to add them to database
//insert label 1 with values for house

```
        {      



string saveQuery = @""insert into LabelLanguage
                          (labelName, englishValue, germanValue) values 
                           (label1, house, hous)  "
        using (IDbConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
               { 
                  connection.Execute(saveQuery);
               }
```

// insert label 2 for values of car

````
     saveQuery = @""insert into LabelLanguage
                               (labelName, englishValue, germanValue) values 
                                (label1, car, Wagen)  "
              using (IDbConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
                    { 
                       connection.Execute(saveQuery);
                    }

         }
 ```

Create a class to hold label values
````

```
public class MyLabelValue
    {
// should match database spellings
        public string labelName{ get; set; }
        public string englishValue{ get; set; }
        public string germanValue{ get; set; }
    }
```

```
add Dapper to the project [ maps classes ]
via nuget package manger

create a method to Get a list of labels and values from database
```

```
public List<MyLabelValue> GetLabelLanguageValues(string languageName )
        {
            using (IDbConnection connection = ConnectionFactory())
            {
                return connection.Query<MyLabelValue>($"SELECT labelName, "+ languageName +" FROM LabelLanguage").ToList();
            }
        }
```

````
Create a method to loop through each label on your form
'''

    void LoopThroughLabels(string languageName )
    {
     Label mylabel;
     list listOfLanguageValues = GetLabelLanguageValues(languageName );

         foreach (Control con in this.Controls) 
         {
             if (con.GetType() == typeof (Label)) //or any other logic
             {
                mylabel = (Label)con;
                foreach (MyLabelValue languageValue in listOfLanguageValues )
                 {
                  if (mylabel.name.ToString() == languageValue.labelName.ToString()
                      {
    ```
//uses reflection so make sure the property GetProperty("languageName ") is how the column in database is spelt and the property of the class MyLabelValue
````

```
    mylabel.Text= languageValue.GetType().GetProperty(languageName ).GetValue(languageValue, null); ;
                  }               
             }


         }
     }
 }
```

```
Note: probably quite a few mistakes in there
and it relies on the exact naming of labels and also of language names
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all if we are talking about **Localization:**

There is a way of doing that.

In your solution explorer, create a folder named: **Resources**

Go to your `Startup.cs`

In your `ConfigureServices` register your Localization Settings for **Resources** folder:

```
services.AddLocalization(options =>
{
      // Store localization files under the Resources folder.
      options.ResourcesPath = "Resources";
});
```

And also in `ConfigureServices` while you are registiring you MVC please add following:

```
services.AddMvc()
     .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)                           
     .SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
         new CultureInfo("en-US"), // => English option
         new CultureInfo("it-it")  // => Italian option
    };
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});
```

And now in your `Cofigure` method please add following:

```
var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);
```

Now please create a `Controller` named could be => `LanguageController.cs`

Please add the following:

```
//This will be your main Cookie Culture Info controller.
public class LanguageController : Controller
{
     [HttpPost]
     public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnURL)
     {
         Response.Cookies.Append(
             CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
             CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture))                
             );

         return LocalRedirect(returnURL);
     }
}
```

Now, you have to create `.resx` files under your  **Resources** File:
Lets say you have a `HomeController.cs` and a `public IActionResult Index()` method,
So, for this page you have to create a `.resx` file like following:

->English 
`Views.Home.Index.en-US.resx`

->Italian
`Views.Home.Index.it-it.resx`

These **.resx** files are easy to use, like an excell view and a xml format you have to give same keys but different values for each **.resx** file.

**Example:**

-> en-US.resx -> **Key:** Hello and **Value:** Hello

-> it-it.resx -> **Key:** Hello and **Value:** Ciao

Now you can use this under your **Views** folder in `Index.cshtml` file:

**Example:** `<text>@Localizer["Hello"]</text>` 
Now you can create a form in your website, whereever you'd like to create, lets assume you want to create it on your `navbar`

Go to your `navbar.cshtml` (In my example, this can be any different page in your site)

And add following top of your `.cshtml`

```
@{
    var requestCulture = Context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
    var cultureItems = LocOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.DisplayName })
        .ToList();
}
```

also create a form for post data to `LanguageController.cs -> SetLanguage()`: (Below form's design could be the worse... sorry)

```
<form asp-controller="Language" asp-action="SetLanguage" id="selectLanguage" 
      asp-route-returnURL="@Context.Request.Path" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <ul class="navbar mt-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">               
               <button name="culture" value="@cultureItems[1].Value" type="submit">
                    <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us mr-1"> </span> 
               @cultureItems[0].Value
               </button>
               <br />
               <button name="culture" value="@cultureItems[2].Value" type="submit">
                    <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-it mr-1"> </span> 
                @cultureItems[1].Value</button>
          </li>
   </ul>
</form>
```

**Note:** Because of `.resx` files are in XML format you can use them everywhere and its so light to use.